# Relationship between points and air miles

Tags: canada, reward-program, airline, points

Let us say I have Air Canada Aeroplan card, and if I shop at certain retailers, I accumulate points.
Now let us say a particular flight on air Canada cost 100,000 miles. How to know how many points are worth a mile? Is this relationship changing continuously, and if so where can I find the most recent conversion rate?

The plan is that when I buy something , I should have at least a rough idea how many 'miles' I am accumulating, not just how many points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit card terms will tell you this. If I recall correctly, the Citibank American Airline card gave 1 mile per dollar spent. And miles can range in value based on the ticket you buy, but 2 cents was an average miles value.

Comment: Thanks. So if i buy miles...i pay 1 $/mile, but if I need to convert miles to dollars to buy an airline ticket, then 1 mile = 2 cents? That is some spread! How is it ever proftable for me? The only profit is if the sign up bonus is huge

Comment: Oops. You spend a dollar on a soda, and get 1 mile. The mile is worth about 2 cents. So 25000 miles, say, will get you a round trip ticket worth $500 or so. The value depends on the ticket. I recently gave a fellow blogger friend 35,000 miles and she got a ticket that would have cost $1000. So that was worth nearly 3 cents a mile.